# No method error for validates_inclusion_of

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord

I have a Model Representative

```
class Representative< ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_inclusion_of :gender, :in => Representative.genders

  def self.genders
    %w(M F)
  end
end
```

When I write the validation line before the genders function definition it does not work it gives and undefined method genders error. When I write the validation below the function it works, Why is this happening? I am used to calling and defining functions without having to worry about the sequence, am I getting something really wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby executes the code line by line, like shime explains.
Therefore, at the time it run the `validates_inclusion_of`, it try to find the method `genders`. It cannot find that method at that time, so it raise an error. Better to move that method up or simply define constant.

Better check the backtrace in the error, and try to understand it.

```
class Representative < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.genders
    %w(M F)
  end

  validates_inclusion_of :gender, :in => Representative.genders
end
```

Here is how you define constant so that you can access it later on by calling `Representative::GENDERS`.

```
class Representative < ActiveRecord::Base
  GENDERS = %w(M F)

  validates_inclusion_of :gender, :in => GENDERS
end
```

Comment: I get what i was doing wrong. What do you mean by simply define a constant ?

Answer (score 0):

You're here passing a method call as an argument to the other method.

Let me explain this with the example

```
class Printer
  def print(something)
    print something
  end


  print sheet

  def sheet
    "sheet!"
  end
end
```

Here you'll get a `NameError` - undefined local variable or method `sheet`.

What happens is that ruby tries to evaluate your expression, and sees that `sheet` is a method call. It then calls the method and throws this kind of error.

If you move the method definition above the method call - it's defined.

```
class Printer
  def print(something)
    puts something
  end

  def sheet
    "sheet!"
  end

  print sheet
end
```

Comment: sorry about that .. it was a typo while posting the question in my code i have it correct validates_inclusion_of and it is giving me error undefined method genders for class #XXXYY